# How to include multiple domains in an spf TXT Record

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, txt-record

I am looking to setup a TXT spf record that has 2 included domains... individually:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

and

```
v=spf1 include:otherdomain.com ~all
```

What is the proper way of combining them into a single item?

Comment: can anyone tell me what this ?all mean,  sometimes they have this sign  ~all

Answer (score 371, accepted):

`v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:otherdomain.com ~all`

There's no restriction against including multiple names in a single entry; [Hotmail, for instance](https://serverfault.com/questions/265277/what-does-smtp-designate-term-mean/265281#265281), takes this to extremes.  Note that multiple includes, or nested ones, need to stay under the limit of 10 total DNS lookups for the whole SPF check.

Comment: [RFC 4408 §10.1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4408.html#section-10.1): *SPF implementations MUST limit the number of mechanisms and modifiers that do DNS lookups to at most 10 per SPF check, including any lookups caused by the use of the "include" mechanism or the "redirect" modifier.*

Comment: @mr.spuratic Good point - that was poor wording, as I was trying to say "you can do greater than one."  Edited.

Comment: Do you have to use the word include each time? Would this be a valid format? (minus the fake domain and internal address space) "v=spf1 include:www.domain.com ip4:10.10.10.0/24 ip4:10.10.100.0/24 a -all" I checked it against http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html and it said it was valid.

Comment: @k1DBLITZ Yes, that's valid - `include` is just for when you're using records from another domain.

Comment: can anyone tell me what this ?all mean, sometimes they have this sign ~all

Comment: `+all     pass     Allow all mail`

`-all     fail     Only allow mail that matches one of the parameters (IPv4, MX, etc) in the record`

`~all     softfail     Allow mail whether or not it matches the parameters in the record`

`?all     neutral     No policy statement`

Comment: There is also [a limit of 255 characters](https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00356/0/Can-I-have-a-TXT-or-SPF-record-longer-than-255-characters.html) for an SPF record.

Answer (score 1):

It look like you can merge both together into one entry. Lenovo.com appears to be an example of this:

```
v=spf1 include:spf.messagelabs.com include:_netblocks.eloqua.com ~all
```

Comment: Their current SPF record is "v=spf1 include:spf.messagelabs.com ~all v=spf1 mx/24 mx:include:ibm.com/24 ~all" Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Perform a "nslookup -type=txt lenovo.com" (without the quotes) and it should be self-explanatory.

Comment: It's as the OP was looking for in a - "spf record that has 2 included domains..."

Comment: Okay, I thought you meant one include statement like "include:spf.messagelabs.com,include:ibm.com"

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with spacing but use a tool to verify the 10 DNS lookup limit has not been breached. You cannot have multiple SPF records either so you may need to be brutal with the shortlist.

As an aside, you do not need `a:foo.com` if you have `include:foo.com` in the same string. If this is is a fallacious remark, please comment below.