# How to include multiple spf TXT records with domain and sub domains

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, txt-record

Already [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/283125/how-to-include-multiple-domains-in-an-spf-txt-record) is similar question, but my requirement is different.

We are using Google apps for example.com for our corporate mails , we also use sub domains in mail chimp for sending mass mails.
Recently we had some delivery issues with Google Apps, our mails was reported as spam by receipent mail server.

We contacted Google support and they adviced to combine spf records to single line using [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4568483?hl=en&ref_topic=2759192) article.

Here is the spf Record in Go Daddy

**Google Apps**

**Domain:** example.com

```
txt     @   v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all     1 Hour
```

**Mail Chimp**

**1. Sub Domain:** offers.example.com

```
txt     offers v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net ?all     1 Hour
```

**2. Sub Domain:** food.example.com

```
txt     food  v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net ?all  1 Hour
```

Now how to make mail chimp and google apps spf records into single line ? because host value for google apps is @ and for mail chimp host value is offers for one sub domain and food for another sub domain ?

Can we use common host value for both Google Apps and Mail Chimp ?

Any help would be great.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to merge the two records unless the sub-domains are sending mail as the main domain or vice-versa. The linked article only describes how to merge two records, and has no information on under which domain you should create the record. Perhaps they want you to add the same merged record under all three domains.

Comment: @LarsLindNilsson , I have to contact Go Daddy our domain registrar to check on how to add common `SPF` record for all two mail providers with different sub domains in single line.

Comment: You could create the merged record under spf.expample.com, and then change the SPF records for the three domains to `v=spf1 include:spf.example.com ?all`. But that still doesn't explain why you are having the problems, if the mails are always being sent from the "correct" servers.

Comment: can anyone tell me what this ?all mean, the ?all sign , sometimes they have this sign - ~all